# Why was this question removed?

Tags: discussion

Why was this question removed?

[The gods who promised to return](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/45803/the-gods-who-promised-to-return)

> Why do ancient gods have to promise to return?
>   Has the return of the gods been a deception of public opinion?
>   Or have there really been gods who have promised to return?
>   Can the gods return to Earth and be mistakenly overthrown by anti-aircraft!?
>   Or can the atomic weapons of the gods reach the ground before them?
>   Where can I find the materials about the ancient gods who promised to return?

Answer (score 9):

I removed that question because it is not a question about history.

Comment: @Achmed - Just to elaborate, it appears to be more about Mythology, which there is a whole other SE site for. However, I doubt the question would fly there either, as it contains multiple unsupported assertions (both explicit and implicit). But I'm not an expert at what's on-topic there.

Comment: I was looking for historical texts about ancient gods, how can historical texts not be historical!?

Comment: @T.E.D.
this is the question
Where can I find the materials about the ancient gods who promised to return?
but
I wanted to give more information to the reader.
In my opinion, this is the right of the reader to know why I am interested in this subject.

Comment: Do you want to be surprised by the superpower gods like the Inca tribes who were surprised by the superpower Europeans?